# Requests ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to get image data from a particular url (see code below). Their security is pretty outdated (see SSL report below), but I need to connect to it anyway. I am able to fetch the image using my browser.

This is what I try:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.bestseller.com/webseller/psp.show_picture?picturesId=2367737&thumb=false'
requests.get(url)
```

The error I get is:

```
...
    File "/path/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)
```

I get the same error when I add the argument `verify=False`.

I have installed `requests` using `pip install requests[security]`. This is the relevant `pip freeze` output:

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
certifi==2017.11.5
cryptography==2.1.4
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.3
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
requests==2.8.1
urllib3==1.22
```

Other configuration prints:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
>>> print(backend.openssl_version_text())
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

Is there a way to disable setting up / verifying SSL, or if not, how do I find out which cipher I need to add and how do I do this?

When I try to write my own adapter:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context

# This is the 2.11 Requests cipher string, containing 3DES.
CIPHERS = (
    'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:'
    'DH+HIGH:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:'
    '!eNULL:!MD5'
)

class DESAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS)
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = context
        return super(DESAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount(url, DESAdapter())
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init_poolmanager'
```

[image: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.bestseller.com]

Comment: `requests==2.8.1` is quite old. The latest is `2.18.4`. You could try updating: `pip install -U requests[security]`

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't change anything.

Comment: Your indentation of `DESAdapter.init_poolmanager` is wrong. I just checked `HTTPAdapter` in `requests 2.18.4` and it has an `init_poolmanager` method so this should definitely work.

Comment: Mmm, indentation went wrong when copy-pasting to SO I see.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have circumvented the issue using library `pycurl`.

```
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.error import URLError

import pycurl
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


def _create_attachment_from_url(url: str):
    """
    Fetch the image from the given URL and save it as an attachment
    """

    try:
        file = _fetch_file_using_urllib(url)
    except URLError:
        file = _fetch_file_using_pycurl(url)

    return file


def _fetch_file_using_urllib(url: str) -> (File, str):
    response = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
    contents = open(response[0], 'rb')
    file = File(contents)
    return file


def _fetch_file_using_pycurl(url: str) -> (File, str):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    try:
        c.setopt(c.URL, url)
        c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
        c.perform()
        contents = buffer.getvalue()
        file = ContentFile(contents)
    finally:
        c.close()
    return file
```